# Plot keyboard layout in R

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, mapping, keyboard-shortcuts

I am creating a Shiny app with customised keyboard shortcuts (eg, if someone presses `s`, some data will be submitted). For this, I would find it really useful to produce a "plot" of the keyboard layout in R to map the keys to their shortcut functions and display in the app.

These are some dummy shortcuts:

```
actions <- c("back", "next", "update", "submit") 
keys <- c(",", ".", "u", "s")
keycode <- c(188,190,85,83)
data.frame(actions, keys, keycode)

# actions  keys keycode
# back      ,     188
# next      .     190
# update    u      85
# submit    s      83
```

I would like something like this:

[image]

But I want choose what to display inside every key. The only remotely [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10670751/r-plot-human-body-in-2d) I could find is not very helpful. I wonder if this can be plotted as a map, maybe?

Comment: You're probably best off simply plotting that png image and then plot some extra labels on top of that. You should also be aware that different users have different keyboard lay-outs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A very naive approach would be to simply draw the keyboard using `geom_rect()` for example.
The first step is to create each line, I did it separately because it makes it really easy not getting lost.
Changing any key to another value is quite straightforward since they are easy to pinpoint inside each dataframe.

```
library(ggplot2)
#1st line from top
df1=data.frame(xmin=c(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13),
              xmax=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,15),
              ymin=rep(4,14),
              ymax=rep(5,14),
              value=c("'","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","0","-","=","backspace"))
#2nd line from top
df2=data.frame(xmin=c(0,1.5,2.5,3.5,4.5,5.5,6.5,7.5,8.5,9.5,10.5,11.5,12.5,13.5),
               xmax=c(1.5,2.5,3.5,4.5,5.5,6.5,7.5,8.5,9.5,10.5,11.5,12.5,13.5,15),
               ymin=rep(3,14),
               ymax=rep(4,14),
               value=c("tab","Q","W","E","R","T","Y","U","I","O","P","[","]","enter"))
#3rd line from top
df3=data.frame(xmin=c(0,1.75,2.75,3.75,4.75,5.75,6.75,7.75,8.75,9.75,10.75,11.75,12.75,13.75),
               xmax=c(1.75,2.75,3.75,4.75,5.75,6.75,7.75,8.75,9.75,10.75,11.75,12.75,13.75,15),
               ymin=rep(2,14),
               ymax=rep(3,14),
               value=c("caps","A","S","D","F","G","H","J","K","L",":","@","~","enter"))
#4th line from top
df4=data.frame(xmin=c(0,1.5,2.5,3.5,4.5,5.5,6.5,7.5,8.5,9.5,10.5,11.5,12.5),
               xmax=c(1.5,2.5,3.5,4.5,5.5,6.5,7.5,8.5,9.5,10.5,11.5,12.5,15),
               ymin=rep(1,13),
               ymax=rep(2,13),
               value=c("shiftr","|","Z","X","C","V","B","N","M","<",">","?","shiftr"))
#5th line from top
df5=data.frame(xmin=c(0,1.5,2.5,4,10,11.5,12.5,13.5),
               xmax=c(1.5,2.5,4,10,11.5,12.5,13.5,15),
               ymin=rep(0,8),
               ymax=rep(1,8),
               value=c("ctrll","winl","altl","space","altgr","winr","menu","ctrlr"))

#putting it together
df=rbind(df1,df2,df3,df4,df5)

ggplot(df,aes(xmin = xmin, xmax = xmax, ymin = ymin, ymax = ymax))+
  geom_rect(colour="black")+geom_text(aes(x=(xmin+xmax)/2,y=(ymin+ymax)/2,label=value))+
  theme_void()
```

[image]

**Note:** This is far from perfect (the "enter" key is split into 2) but that might give you some idea or a base to work on.